# Why is very little capacity available on my 8GB SD card?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I'm using an 8GB SD card and installed Raspbian which is 3.9GB large.
I suppose that about 4GB should be available, but it isn't.
When I type `'df -ah'` on my Raspberry pi, it shows

[image]

Only 65MB is available....

And this is `diskutil list` on my Mac OS X

[image]

And I did not install nothing but open-ssh..and vim..

Comment: As an aside, this was a very well written question. I appreciate the amount of information that you included without prompt. If you have questions in the future, please keep up the good form. It makes helping people so much easier!

Comment: Why pasting text as screenshots?

Comment: @RQDQ There is no useful color coding in the example.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It appears that you have not yet expanded your file system.

1. Run `sudo raspi-config`.
2. Select *Expand Filesystem* (the first option at the time of this writing), and follow the instructions.

After rebooting the system you should have significantly more space available.

Comment: Is my assumption correct that there is actually more than 65MB available, but that it's only showing 1 partition (i.e. the FAT32 partition)?

Comment: @GroundZero Yes. The image that was written to the SD card was of a certain size and contains a filesystem that "knows" this. When the image is written to the larger SD card it is written "as is" and is not expanded because that is best done from within the Raspian OS itself. That is what is done via the 1st menu-option in raspi-config. Most Raspian "getting started" manuals cover this .... The poster must have missed that.

Comment: @GroundZero: I started to edit my answer to address your question, but it's honestly another question entirely. If you post your comment as a question, I'd be happy to give you a detailed answer. In short, Tonny is correct.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Thanks but that won't be necessary. I just wanted to confirm my thoughts on this. The reason that the OS only shows 65MB is because it's only showing the size of the FAT32 partition. Which doesn't necessarily mean that there's only 65MB available. Any other filesystem that is readable to the host, would show up seperately

Comment: @MarkBooth: decent point. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

### Option 1:

Step 1: If this isn't a fresh install, back up your data.

Step 2: Run the command: `sudo raspi-config`

Step 3: Choose the option "Expand Filesystem" from the menu.

### Option 2:

Step 1: Back up your data

Step 2: Put the SD card in to your PC/Mac and expand the main partition

Step 3: Put your data back on the SD card

Comment: Option 1 step 0 should still be "back it up".

Comment: If they've only just installed Rasbian, there probably isn't anything to back up.