# 32G SD Card showing almost full with only 4G files on it!

Tags: sd-card, storage

I am a bit confused by the state of the storage on my RPi. I have a 32G SD Card but looking at the following it is nearly full but has only used up 3.8G space!

'df' tells me my /dev/root is 30G in size, 27G used with only 1.5G available.
[image: df -h]

'parted' tells me a similar story, two partitions which are in total 31.9G in size.
[image: parted -l]

But 'du' tells me that I only have 3.6G of files.

[image: du]

Pi OS details:

[image: lsb-release]

I understand that df and du calculate the space used differently, but what could be going on here that gives such a large difference?

I have tried running raspi-config and the above details do not change (even after a reboot of the pi).
[image: raspi-config--expand-rootfs]

P.s. Sorry for the lack of info to start of with, late night frustration not understanding why my Pi was running out of space!

Comment: you probably haven't extended the filesystem - though, `df` suggests you have - odd ... what is the *actual* output of `parted -l`

Comment: Which filesystem do you use? Btrfs is known to be a bit confusing about free space calculations. I will give you a different answer depending on that information.

Comment: note: extending the partition doesn't extend the filesystem - the raspi-config way below should do both for you

Comment: "am I missing something" such as some data about what you see, what OS etc.

Comment: -1 for posting error messages as screenshots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is very little capacity available on my 8GB SD card?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41767/why-is-very-little-capacity-available-on-my-8gb-sd-card)

Comment: I didn't post an error message, I posted an image showing that I took the action that was provided as an answer.

Comment: Raspbian Jessie is oldstable. Is it an option to install a stable Raspbian Stretch? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Release_table

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you did not expand your file system yet. Try

```
sudo raspi-config --expand-rootfs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my edited question above I show that I have already done this but it hasn't made any difference.