# df shows SD card full but I can't figure out what it's full of

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I have a Pi 4 running Raspberry Pi OS that I use as an Emby server. It's just a fresh install of Raspberry Pi OS with Samba and Emby, nothing else. It has been working fine for months, but yesterday Emby wouldn't start due to a "No space left on device" error.

I checked with `df` and sure enough there's no space on the internal SD card:

```
user@Server:/mnt $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        30G   29G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        805M     0  805M   0% /dev
tmpfs           934M     0  934M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           934M   11M  924M   2% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           934M     0  934M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   50M  203M  20% /boot
/dev/sdd1       3.6T  2.5T 1010G  72% /mnt/storage1
/dev/sdc1       3.6T  2.5T 1004G  72% /mnt/storage2
/dev/sdb1       9.1T  5.0T  3.7T  58% /mnt/media2
/dev/sda1       9.1T  5.0T  3.7T  58% /mnt/media1
tmpfs           187M     0  187M   0% /run/user/1000
```

So what's taking up all the space? I ran `du` in `/` to check:

```
user@Server:/ $ sudo du -sh *
0   bin
50M boot
0   dev
3.9M    etc
48K home
0   lib
16K lost+found
4.0K    media
15T mnt
240M    opt
du: cannot access 'proc/1036/task/1036/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/1036/task/1036/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/1036/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access 'proc/1036/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
0   proc
24K root
11M run
0   sbin
4.0K    srv
0   sys
32K tmp
1.3G    usr
1.5G    var
```

I don't understand the four lines about `proc/1036`, but otherwise this all looks correct. There's 15 TB in `mnt`, which is on external drives. And everything else adds up to about 5 GB. So there should be around 25 GB free on the SD card. But there's not.

[This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41767/why-is-very-little-capacity-available-on-my-8gb-sd-card) describes a similar problem that was resolved by expanding the fileystem. I definitely expanded the file system when I first set it up. Just in case, I ran `sudo raspi-config` and expanded it again. No change. So that doesn't seem to be the issue. [Another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81530/32g-sd-card-showing-almost-full-with-only-4g-files-on-it) shows a very similar issue, but with no resolution.

How can I figure out what is taking up all my space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/57149): There were large files in the mount directory (on the system SD card) for one of my external drives. With the drive mounted, that directory is completely hidden.

I have a nightly `cron` job that runs `rsync` to clone one of my external media drives to another. At some point the backup drive became unmounted while the primary was still mounted. So when `rsync` tried to clone `/mnt/media1` to `/mnt/media2`, it was unknowingly writing to the `/mnt/media2` directory on the system SD card. It wrote 29 GB and filled up the card then quit. Then the next time I rebooted, the media2 drive mounted successfully *over* `/mnt/media2`, *hiding* the 29 GB backup from `du` and every other way I looked.

Once I unmounted the external drives and took a look it was obvious. I deleted the files from `/mnt/media2` and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I ALWAYS check that the target drive is mounted in RW mode. Otherwise rsync will still try to copy somewhere, and may copy to your SD Card (until full).

```
BACKUP_MOUNTED1=$(mount | awk '/PiData/ {print $6}' | grep "rw")
```

You may find the following useful to check SD usage.
It works on any directory including `/` and excludes virtual files.

```
#! /bin/bash
# 2021-02-06
# Print directory usage - sorted by size

if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    UDIR='.'
else
    UDIR=$1
fi

if [ $UDIR == '/' ]; then
    # exclude virtual directories, mount points etc which don't physically exist
    sudo du -hd1 --exclude proc --exclude run --exclude sys  --exclude dev  --exclude boot --exclude mnt  --exclude media $UDIR | sort -h
else
    sudo du -hd1 $UDIR | sort -h
fi
```